# Deactivate duplicate data based on two group by columns with check not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have this following query to return duplicate rows by 2 columns but it returns rows with NULL values. I would like to return rows with NOT NULL for both columns. Also how can I deactivate duplicate record with old ID?

```
With deactivaterows as (

  Select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1, col2) as cnt from TABLE1 t)

Select * from deactivaterows where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want row_number not count(*):

```
with deactivaterows as
(
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by t.col1, t.col2 order by (select null)) as rn
from TABLE1
where t.col1 is not null and t.col2 is not null
)
select * from deactivaterows where rn > 1
```

Comment: If you use this, keep in mind it will return all but one of the duplicate rows, and I recommend using an `order by` in your `over` statement to make sure you get the ones that are actually duplicates, and not the one you want to keep.

Comment: @TimLeaf The problem statement needs clarification. I was mainly pointing out that row_number() should be used instead of count().

Comment: This is definitely a good point, especially if they are wanting to automatically deactivate only the newest created rows for example, leaving the oldest row untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) 
from TABLE1 
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null
group by col1, col2 
having count(*) > 1
```

The `having` command is great, it filters results *after* the `group by` and the `select`. You can always throw in a `where` regardless, and this will compare before you start grouping, counting or selecting anything.

Alternatively, you can certainly modify your existing solution by throwing in a `where` clause without issue:

```
With deactivaterows as (

  Select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1, col2) as cnt from TABLE1 t 
  where col1 is not null and col2 is not null)

Select * from deactivaterows where cnt > 1;
```